# Compiler asking for optional methods from Collections to be overridden

Tags: java, collections, erasure

I'm creating a class-wide project with my school mates, I'm supposed to create pull requests for some functions, but I'm having some problems just creating the class and overriding the methods in a way that it would just compile (I don't need to write the methods at this moment, that's the project, I just need it to compile). I've found most methods are working (or at least the compiler is not complaining), but I'm confused about a few things:

- Compiler complaining about methods that are optional (like set, and addAll)
- The method addAll, although it was added, complains that it wasn't overridden, although it was, and when I add the other addAll method for it, then I get an erasure error as well.

I've read a bunch about it, but I couldn't find a proper conclusion on how to solve it. I'm just using Atom to write my code, and the Terminal, no fancy IDE (perhaps I should learn one).

In case it isn't clear, I'm just looking to have the stubs of the methods available, not an all around answer for every single method, since this is the project with the class.

```
  // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class SkipList<E> implements List<E>
{
    // compiler complaining, then added, although optional
    public E set(int index, E element)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    // compiler complaining, then added, although optional
    public boolean addAll(Collection <? extends E> c)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Group 1
    public boolean add(E e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void add(int index, E e)
    {

    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection c)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object o)
    {
        int index = 0;
        return index;
    }

    public int lastIndexOf(Object o)
    {
        int index = 0;
        return index;
    }

    // Group 2
    public boolean contains(Object o)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection c)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        List<E> sub = new SkipList<>();
        return sub;
    }

    // Group 3
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        int size = 0;
        return size;
    }

    public void clear()
    {

    }

    public E get(int index)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public E getQuantile(double quantile) // e.g. 0 = minimum, 0.5 = median, 1 = max
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    // Group 4
    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator()
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    // Group 5
    public E remove(int index)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean removeAll(Collection c)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean retainAll(Collection c)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Group 6
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        return hashCode;
    }

    public Object[] toArray()
    {
        Object[] arr = new Object[0];
        return arr;
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Those methods are **not** optional.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Interesting. I thought what was as "optional operation" on the API made that optional. Time to learn how they describe what optionals are. :)

Comment: "Optional operation" means that the implementation of a method can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of actually performing the function.  That means that if you say `List<E> list = someMethodCall();` so that you don't know the exact type of the list, you have to be careful about using `addAll` or other optional operations, since they might not work.  But the methods still have to be overridden if they're abstract.

Comment: Interesting, @ajb, that clarifies it a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when reading the API, for some reason I glossed over the other parameter for the addAll method, that led me to believe something else was wrong. I changed the method with the correct parameters and it compiled.

```
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection <? extends E> c)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It also may be easier to do `SkipList<T> extends AbstractList<T>` rather than `SkipList<T> implements List<T>`.

Comment: Cool beans, @markspace. Could you expand on why, please? :)